# Making a Time series and looping it

Tags: r, loops, time-series

I want to create a loop or a function with which i can get 100 different timeseries of lenghth 100 stored into different vectors
The function I am using to generate time series is below :-

```
arima.sim(100,list(ar = c(0.5,0.2), ma = -0.2))
```

From the above code I generate A TIMESERIES WITH LENGTH 100 but what should I do to get such 100 timeseries ??

Comment: `replicate(100, stats::arima.sim(n = 100,list(ar = c(0.5,0.2), ma = -0.2)))` - in each column you will have one timeseries.

Comment: For 100-column matrix, use @missuse's solution above with `replicate` (wrapper to `sapply`). For list of 100 vectors add argument, `simplify=FALSE`.

Comment: @missuse  thank you so much it simplifies a lot but what if i want to create 100 different vectors from it should i just slice the matrix ??

Comment: having 100 vectors in one object such as a matrix or a list (as @Parfait suggested) is much better then having 100 vector objects in the environment. You can just use `lapply` to iterate over the list or `apply` with `margin=2` to iterate over the matrix and do what you intend with the time series.